# python3 не видит selenium, хотя он установлен

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, модули

Код, из-за которого что-то не так

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
```

Selenium установлен много раз и многими способами через pip.
Pip его видит:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Peter\Progs\python\FipiParser>pip list
    Package    Version
    ---------- -------
    pip        20.0.2
    selenium   3.141.0
    setuptools 41.2.0
    urllib3    1.25.7
```

Но при запуске python его не видит, возможно из-за первой строчки, но убрать я ее не могу, тк полезут ошибки с комментариями.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Peter\Progs\python\FipiParser>parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Peter\Progs\python\FipiParser\parser.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

Comment: Тут нужны еще несколько переменных из уравнения - сколько интерпретаторов стоит в вашей системе?
Какая версия python прописана в переменной PATH?
Без шебэнга(первой строки вылезает ли та же самая ошибка первой в списке?

Comment: без первой строки ошибка остается и появляется та, которую 1 строка фиксила.

Comment: Удалил р2.7 и заработало.